# Linking to specific ID on another Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, html

I have a header.php, that appears in every single page on my blog, with a navbar that looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(4); ?>">Logistics</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(5); ?>#contact">Contact</a></li>      
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But when I click the anchor tag linking to #contact, which is located in page with id 5, as you can see by the php code, nothing happens. I tried using a slash (/#contact) but I keep getting the same behavior. Isn't this the correct way of linking to a specific id on another page?

EDIT: I also have some smooth scrolling code (below) which I think may be related to my issue.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function () {

     // Add smooth scrolling to all links
     $( "a" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

         // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
         if ( this.hash !== "" ) {

             // Prevent default anchor click behavior
             event.preventDefault();

             // Store hash
             var hash = this.hash;

             // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
             // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
             $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                scrollTop: $( hash ).offset().top
             }, 800, function () {

                  // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                  window.location.hash = hash;
              } );
         } // End if
       } );
      } );
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this looks correct. It's hard to say what the issue is without a complete example.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct id? Go with inspect element on that <li> and check if the link is there. Also, as a test you can check with another permalink.

Comment: @Vladut I am sure because it all works ok if I'm on page with ID 5 (it then scrolls to #contact). It just doesn't work if it's a different page!

Comment: Hmmm. Can you give a link to your website?

Comment: @Vladut yes, of course. I edited the question adding some smooth scroll jquery I also had that I believe might be conflicting with the code. The website is http://www.mmpplasticos.com.br/home (it's kinda hidden from being index.php because it's not ready).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a javascript error.

```
<script>
            $( document ).ready( function () {
                // Add smooth scrolling to all links
                $( "a" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

                    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
                    if ( this.hash !== "" ) {
                        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                        event.preventDefault();

                        // Store hash
                        var hash = this.hash;

                        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                        $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                            scrollTop: $( hash ).offset().top
                        }, 800, function () {

                            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                            window.location.hash = hash;
                        } );
                    } // End if
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

Here is the problem. On the home page you have a div with id #contato. On the other pages it is not there.

```
$( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                                scrollTop: $( hash ).offset().top
                            }, 800, function () {

                                // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                                window.location.hash = hash;
                            } );
```

Your hash var's value  is "#contato", but when js tries to get it's offset you recieve an error saying that it's impossible to read property top of 'undefined'. So, you can try to remove that part of the script from the other pages and only keep it on home. This should work like a charm. If you have any question, please ask.

**LE**: I'd recommend this method for smooth scroll (I didn't tested it for your case, but it always worked for me)

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I created a new header with the smooth scroll code to be used when on home and another header without such code to be used elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php echo get_page_link(5)."#contact"; ?>
```

instead of get permalink function

Comment: Doesn't work! I'll edit the question because I also have some smooth scroll javascript which may be conflicting with the code